# Convert Mask-RCNN model for android with tflite

Tags: python, android, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to deploy this mask-rcnn model in android. I was able to load the keras weight, freeze the model and convert it to .tflite model using tflite 1.13 toco using [this script](https://gist.github.com/bmabir17/754a6e0450ec4fd5e25e462af949cde6).

It seems this model uses some tf_ops that is not supported in tflite. Thus I had to use

```
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
```

to convert the model. Now when I try to infer this model using python interpreter, I get segmentation error in interpreter.invoke() and the python script crashes.

```
def run_tf_model(model_path="mask_rcnn_coco.tflite"):
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    # Get input and output tensors.
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]
    print(" input_details", input_details)
    print("output_details",output_details)

    # Test model on random input data.
    input_shape = input_details['shape']
    print("input_shape tflite",input_shape)
    input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()

    # The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
    # Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details['index'])
    print(output_data)
```

Thus I am unable to find out if my converted model has been converted correctly or not.

P.S. I am planning to use this model in android, but I have little experience with android(java or kotlin) tflite api. If any one can point out any resources for learning about that would be also be helpful.

Edit: I also tried to run the inference on android with java api. But get the following error `tensorflow/lite/kernels/gather.cc:80 0 <= axis && axis < NumDimensions(input).`
[Detailed in this tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39179)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your custom trained tflite model using TFLite python interpreter. [Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```